# NullPointerException in SQLContext.read() Spark

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, avro

I am trying to read JSON records, produced by Kafka, in Spark using SQLContext.read(). Every time NullPointerException appears.

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
       .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
        .setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

    Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton(topicString);
    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", servers);

    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            ssc, String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, 
            kafkaParams, topics);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

    directKafkaStream
        .map(message -> message._2)
        .foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            rdd.foreach(record -> {
                Dataset<Row> ds = sqlContext.read().json(rdd);
            });
         });
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Here is a log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:535)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read(SQLContext.scala:504)
    at SparkJSONConsumer$1.lambda$2(SparkJSONConsumer.java:73)
    at SparkJSONConsumer$1$$Lambda$8/1821075039.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$27.apply(RDD.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$27.apply(RDD.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I assume the problem is due to foreachRDD clause, but can't figure it out. So any suggestions would be great.

Also, I am using sqlContext, because after I plan to serialize records in avro format ("com.databricks.spark.avro"). If there is a way to serialize a string, containing JSON structure, to avro format without defining the schema, you are very welcome to share it!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Spark documentation -
You have to create a SparkSession using the SparkContext that the StreamingContext is using. Furthermore this has to done such that it can be restarted on driver failures. This is done by creating a lazily instantiated singleton instance of SparkSession.

**Refer:**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations

**Solution:**

Create SQLContext like below, just before read json.

```
SQLContext sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate().sqlContext


Dataset<Row> ds = sqlContext.read().json(rdd);
```